# having some trouble with a while loop, and getting an if statement to execute

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This is an exercise we are doing in our last chapter of the book. I covered everything except the if statement that requires the input to follow a number after a comma.

For example: John Doe, nine

output should trigger, comma should follow integer. I am trying to get the if statement to at least recognize that if the input after the comma is not a number then the output if statement should trigger but I can't.

What is working at least is input statements with more than one comma.

The expected format should be:

Jane Doe, 9

```
while (!datapoint.equals("-1")) {
      


  
  System.out.println("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):");
  datapoint = scnr.nextLine();
  
  
  int commaCount = 0;
  
  for( int i= 0; i < datapoint.length(); i++)
  {
      if(datapoint.charAt(i) == ',')
          commaCount++;
  }
  
  if (commaCount > 1) {
      
      System.out.println("Error: Too many commas in input.");
      
  }
  
  if (datapoint.equals("-1")) {
      
      break;
      
  }
  
  if (!datapoint.contains(",")) {
      
      System.out.println("Error: No comma in string.");
      
  }


  
    
  
  if (datapoint.contains(",")) {
      
  String[] values = datapoint.split(",");     
  
  temp1 = values[0];
  temp2 = values[1];
  
  temp1 = temp1.replace(",", "");  // commma removed   ex/ Jane Austen
  temp2 = temp2.replace(" ", "");  // space removed    ex/ 6 
  
  String trigger = temp2;
  
  
  if (values.length == 2)  {
  
  
  if (temp2.length() > 2)   {    //if datapoint does not contain a number after commma
      
      
    System.out.println("Error: Comma not followed by an integer.");  
      
      
      
    }
  
  
  if (trigger.length() < 3) {
      
  int convert = Integer.parseInt(temp2);  // converts string to integer   
  
  System.out.println("Data string: " + temp1); 
  System.out.println("Data integer: " + convert);  // 2 
  
  names.add(temp1);
  ints.add(convert);
  
  }
  
  }
  
  }
       
  
  System.out.println();
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop, back up and take a deep breath ... I seem to be saying that a lot lately.

Break the problem down and then, step by step, try and solve each problem, not try and do the whole thing, because your confused and I'm confused.

If we assume `Jane Doe, 9` is a valid format, then we can start from there.

We can simply split the `String` on the comma doing something like...

```
String[] parts = value.split(",");
```

Based on the "valid" input, we would end up with `["Jane Doe", " 9"]`, sweet.  So we can do a basic validation using something like...

```
if (parts.length == 2) {
    
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input, expecting [String],[int]");
}
```

Okay, sweet.  Now we can valid the individual parts of the `String`

First, we should check to see if the name isn't blank.  Then we should try and determine if the second part is an integer or not.   Not, here's a neat trick I think people miss out on - you can use more then one `Scanner` and use it validate the `String`

```
if (parts[0].isBlank()) {
    System.out.println("Name can not be blank");
} else {
    Scanner parser = new Scanner(parts[1].trim());
    if (parser.hasNextInt()) {
        int intValue = parser.nextInt();
    } else {
        System.out.println("[" + parts[1] + "] is not a valid integer");
    }
}
```

Now, we can do some quick validation...

```
String value = "Jane Doe, 9";
String[] parts = value.split(",");
if (parts.length == 2) {
    if (parts[0].isBlank()) {
        System.out.println("Name can not be blank");
    } else {
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(parts[1].trim());
        if (parser.hasNextInt()) {
            int intValue = parser.nextInt();
            System.out.println(parts[0] + " = " + intValue);
        } else {
            System.out.println("[" + parts[1] + "] is not a valid integer");
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input, expecting [String],[int]");
}
```

Just change the `value` variable and double check your...my logic, quick simple and clean.

Once you have that, then you can start worrying about including the loop and getting input from other sources...

Honestly, I think the `do-while` is underrated.  Think about it, you MUST do a least one interaction of the loop, so why check the exit condition at the start!?

```
boolean stop = false;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):");
    String value = scnr.nextLine();
    // Handle the exit condition first, get it out of the way
    if ("-1".equals(value)) {
        stop = true;
    } else {
        String[] parts = value.split(",");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            if (parts[0].isBlank()) {
                System.out.println("Name can not be blank");
            } else {
                Scanner parser = new Scanner(parts[1].trim());
                if (parser.hasNextInt()) {
                    int intValue = parser.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(parts[0] + " = " + intValue);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("[" + parts[1] + "] is not a valid integer");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, expecting [String],[int]");
        }
    }
} while (!stop);
```

Comment: I looked at your code and what I ended up doing what using parts.length to my advantage. Check out my final code Mad. Now it works.